# sum query with condition then put result inside textbox

Tags: c#

table name:t

column 1: userr - varchar

column 2: spent - int

column 3: year - varchar

column 4: month - varchar

column 5: day - varchar

in form insert new expense: i add day,month,year seperately so i can run my below query on them...

want to sum (spent) column inside (t) table, using three condition's:

1. where month(column)=datetimepicker1.value.month
2. where year(column)=datetimepicker1.value.year
3. where userr(column)=textbox1.text

and then put the result(SumOfAll) inside textBox2.Text

what i tried:

```
      try
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=SlaveOfAllah-PC;Initial Catalog=expense;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlCon.Open();
            string commandString = "select SUM(CASE WHEN year = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Year + "' and month = '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Month + "' and userr = '" + textBox1.Text + "' THEN spent ELSE 0 END)SumOfAll from t";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);
            SqlDataReader read = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (read.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = read["SumOfAll"].ToString();
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("oops.");
        }
```

help appreciated..

Comment: a) Read up on SQL Injection b) To filter by year and month, you check that the date in the database is >= `1st of the month you are interested in` and < `1st of the next month`. c) Move your date filter from the `SELECT` to the `WHERE`.

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` for the table you are querying.

Comment: Why are you storing year, month and day as separate columns? Why not use the `date` data type?

Comment: what i wanna do is:
1. i sum total spent money for current month(this is addition form)
2. if (sum<100,000) allow addition of new spent data, else (msgbox("exceeded allowed monthly spend, wait for next month")
AND reason i use them seperately, is cause i don't know how to these query's if stored together